# Org-mode Agenda view - how to turn on and off tasks with deadlines

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

In my work routine, I schedule tasks to days of the weeks according to their urgency and effort levels. If there is a deadline of a scheduled task two of them (one entry for deadlined and one for scheduled) are shown in the agenda view of the current day.

Although I can remove scheduled entry by

```
(setq org-agenda-skip-scheduled-if-deadline-is-shown t),
```

it is not the solution that I am after since some of the deadlines that I will work on later still show up on the agenda view. 
I like to see scheduled items instead of the deadline since I am also viewing efforts of the item. However, from time to time I need to see deadlined items so that I can schedule the tasks to the days of the week.

What I really want to do is turning on and off deadlined items when I need to. There should be an easy command but I could not find it, I would appreciate any help.

Best,

Comment: You want to look into `org-agenda-custom-commands` and set up a few different searches that you can choose from when you type `M-x org-agenda`  Here is a link to the manual to get you started:  http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-custom-agenda-commands.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Short answer: Press '!'.

C-h m in the agenda opens a help buffer containing the line

!               org-agenda-toggle-deadlines

Comment: Great, that's just what I wanted!